# Hierarchical clustering plot with high dimensional dataset

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to visualize clusters within a chart. After trying to understand which model is best I end up using a hierarchical clustering. My dataset is pandas dataframe with products in index and ticket in columns. Values are a count of product so that each ticket (imagine a client) buy a set of products.

dataset sample:

```
           ticket1 ticket2 ticket3 
product 1       3        2       6
product 2       8        0       2
product 3       0        10      1
```

I could follow a lot of tutorial explaining hierarchical indexing such as https://www.kaggle.com/heeraldedhia/hierarchical-clustering-for-customer-data

But there is something I am missing as the cluster representation in chart is always picking up some columns which represent for example the age and salary. I don't want to pick up a ticket in my case. I don't care about the ticket and I want to have an overall representation of the PRODUCTS clustered within a chart. Is there a way to come up with this in hierarchical clustering?

FYI my code:

```
data = data
lt.figure(1, figsize = (16 ,8))
dendrogram = sch.dendrogram(sch.linkage(data, method  = "ward"))

plt.title('Dendrogram')
plt.xlabel('product')
plt.ylabel('Euclidean distances')
plt.show()

hc = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = 5, affinity = 'euclidean', linkage ='average')

y_hc = hc.fit_predict(data)
y_hc

data['cluster'] = pd.DataFrame(y_hc)
```

Comment: what do you mean by " ... cluster representation in chart .. "? do you mean in dendrogram?

Comment: @HFZ I already have the dendrogram. I want to display the `y_hc` cluster from the model. But I have only products and the cluster they belong so there is no way to present something meaningful in chart. So what should be done to visualize those clusters?